# PHP - MongoDB Aggregation: GROUP BY on multi-type field

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a field in my MongoDB Collection that is hosting two types of data. In some Documents that field has Integer value, e.g.

```
"campaign_code" : NumberLong(100097)
```

And in other Documents that field has Array value, e.g.

```
"campaign_code" : [NumberLong(100087), NumberLong(100136), NumberLong(100137), NumberLong(100138), NumberLong(100135)]
```

Now, previously I was grouping my result by `"campaign_code"`, but at that time it had only Integer values. Now, the field is having two types of values. The question is is PHP MongoDB driver intelligent to perform the same functionality or do I need to change my code?

My previous PHP code:

```
$pipeline = array(
    array('$match' => array('impression.affiliate_id' => $affiliate_id)),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'impression.campaign_code' => '$impression.campaign_code'
            ),
            'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
        )
    ),
    //sort
    array('$sort' => array('count' => -1))
);
```

I did make some changes and added the following line of code:

```
array('$unwind' => '$impression.campaign_code')
```

But this throws an exception:

```
exception: Value at end of $unwind field path '$impression.campaign_code' must be an Array, but is a NumberLong64
```

Now the exception is quite valid because few documents have only Integer value in the field. Tell me how I can resolve this issue?